# A question based on cutting a wire to form a tetrahedron

Tags: mathematics, geometry

I am trying exercises of Quantitative Aptitude and I am unable to work out how this problem can be solved:

[image]

As a tetrahedron has 6 edges, I thought 5 cuts should be required. But that's wrong.

Answer is:

> C ( 1 )

Comment: This is equivalent to the number of times that one needs to lift the pen from the paper to draw the figure if it's not allowed to re-draw a line

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There needs to be

> **One cut**
>
>  The tetrahedron has 4 vertices, and three wires meet at each – an odd number.
>  So at each vertex there must be one bend (2 wires), and one end (1 wire).
>  So at each vertex, there must be one free end.
>  So there are 4 ends needed, and so two wires are needed, and so one cut is made.
>  Each wire has two bends.
>
>  [image]